# Permission denied while using PHP Mail using Postfix

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I have installed postfix and dovecot properly and did all configurations as per this guide: http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-mail-server-ubuntu-14-04/

But when I try sending mail via terminal like:

```
sudo php -r "mail('xyz@xyz.com', 'test', 'test');"
```

It gives me the error

```
sh: 1: /etc/postfix: Permission denied
```

I tried doing `chmod -R 777` to the `/etc/postfix` directory and I still get the same error.

What should I do to get this working? I just want to send mail from my server to other mails like Gmail (i.e. xyz@xyz.com to abc@gmail.com)

I have even configured the mx records and a records in my dns manager.

If I see the Postfix log, I have this:

`Feb  2 12:30:33 myhost postfix/pickup[16695]: ED7A120FD3: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Feb  2 12:30:33 myhost postfix/cleanup[4891]: ED7A120FD3: message-id=<20160202173033.ED7A120FD3@xyz.com>
Feb  2 12:30:33 myhost postfix/cleanup[4891]: warning: hash:/etc/postfix/virtual is unavailable. open database /etc/postfix/virtual.db: No such file or directory
Feb  2 12:30:33 myhost postfix/cleanup[4891]: warning: hash:/etc/postfix/virtual lookup error for "xyz@xyz.com"
Feb  2 12:30:33 myhost postfix/cleanup[4891]: warning: ED7A120FD3: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for xyz@xyz.com -- message not accepted, try again later`

I am using PHP 7 running Apache 2 on Ubuntu 14.04

(Note: Postfix and dovecot seems to be working cause I did telnet as given in the tutorial and got the correct response.)

Comment: Whatever you are trying to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is wrong and dangerous** -- you should immediately revert to the distribution's default permissions.  Allowing everyone to overwrite system files is lowering the bar tremendously for a malicious user or possible intruder.

Comment: Not a programming question nominating to close as off-topic.  Sound like you have `/etc` in your `PATH` for some odd reason

Comment: I would try testing with swaks, the swiss army knife for smtp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my problem solved. The permission error occured only when accessing Postfix from terminal. It works when accessed from PHP script.

Moreover, I had to modify PHP.ini sendmail path which I set as /etc/postfix before.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to run `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`.

Comment: I have no such directory.. I just tried replacing 

virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
with
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

in my.cnf and I dont get errors in postfix log. but only permission denied error

Comment: `/etc/postfix/virtual` should not be a directory but a file.  `/etc/aliases` and `/etc/postfix/virtual` have slightly different syntax (colons vs. whitespace to separate keys and values) and hence need different tools.  The latter needs be compiled with `sudo newaliases`.

Comment: This is what I have in /etc/postfix

dynamicmaps.cf  main.cf  master.cf  postfix-files  postfix-script  post-install  sasl

nothing else. should I create a file named virtual?

Comment: @vignesh Yes, please do.  Just running `sudo touch /etc/postfix/virtual && sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` should do it.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I am still stuck with permission denied error. But I am able to create virtual now. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: @vignesh sorry, no idea where that error comes from.

Comment: I managed to fix all the errors but I am left with one. 
"lost connection after AUTH from unknown postfix" comes up in the log now